# No such module 'IBMCloudAppID' in xcode 10.2 Swift

Tags: swift3, ibm-cloud, xcode10.2, ibm-appid

I am trying to use IBMCloudAppId is my swift project and getting an error when I am trying to import IBMCloudAppID in my xcode 10.2.

I followed these steps as

1. Open your Xcode project and enable Keychain Sharing (Under project settings > Capabilities > Keychain sharing)
2. Under project setting > info > Url Types, Add $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) as a URL Scheme
3. Add the following import to your AppDelegate.swift file:
   import IBMCloudAppID

Getting an error

```
No such module 'IBMCloudAppID' in xcode 10.2
```

And my POD file looks like

```
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    platform :ios, '10.2'
    pod 'BMSCore', '~> 2.3.1'
    pod 'JOSESwift', '~> 1.1.0'
    pod 'IBMCloudAppID'
end

target 'IBMCloudAppID' do
    use_frameworks!
     pod 'IBMCloudAppID'
     shared_pods
end

target 'IBMCloudAppIDTests' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question

[image]

And after opening workspace, build library first and then project.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't installed pods in the application.

Try with the following steps which should resolve the issue.

- Install Cocoapods in your machine
- Run `pod install` in the terminal at the root of your app project.
- open `your-project.xcworkspace` in Xcode
- Clean and Build the app

Comment: I am installing pod everytime as . pod install --repo-update . and following this link as https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-clientsdk-swift . but getting same errors

Comment: Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using BMSAnalyticsAPI (2.3.1)
Using BMSCore (2.3.7)
Using IBMCloudAppID (6.0.0)
Using JOSESwift (1.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.